# C# infinite recursion during resource lookup

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, storage, mscorlib

I have a problem with this code:

```
if (_updater.IsNewVersionAvailable())
{
    _isolatedStorageFile.CreateDirectory("Folder");
    _isolatedStorageFile.CreateDirectory("Folder2");

    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(_sharedFilesFolder + "\\Folder"))
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
        //_isolatedStorageFile.CreateFile(fileName); // <- same problem

        using (var outputStream = _isolatedStorageFile.OpenFile("Folder/" + fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) // <- here is the problem (I tried with backslash (\\) and also doesnt work.
        {
            using (var inputStream = File.OpenRead(file))
            {
                inputStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the MS Test which called this piece of code I get this error:

[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haf4d.png)

[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89lR4.png)

The folders inside isolated storage are created normally ( I cannot create a file)
The strangest thing is that once when I started the test the file has been created - it was 1/20 runs.

Any idea?

Comment: use `var allFiles=Directory.GetFiles(_sharedFilesFolder + "\\Folder");` and then `foreach (string file in allFiles)`. Does that fix the issue? Also: Use Path.Combine instead of string concatenating paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you can try is, insert this in your code right before you're getting the infinite recursion issue (from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/287e13d0-8387-42c9-ad0a-fea93c95c7fd/mscorlib-recursive-resource-lookup-bug?forum=wpf) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23608)):

```
try
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
catch (NotImplementedException ex)
{
}
```

I was just trying to figure out an issue where we intended to retrieve something from isolated storage, and it got stuck in this inf recursion. I was browsing the .Net and MSTest sources, and it seems that:

1. The file doesn't exist. Its trying to throw a FileNotFoundException from FileStream.Init > WinIOError.
2. To throw the exception, it's trying to get a string with Environment.GetResourceString("IO.FileNotFound_FileName", str), str). From there you get to functions like InternalGetSatelliteAssembly. Its trying to locate mscorlib.
3. Meanwhile, MSTest has defined an AssemblyResolver listener, which get's called at this point. It will iterate over some paths, doing a File.Exists check on them.
4. File.Exist will check for permissions to that file. For code access permissions, it'll throw a SecurityException with the parameter: Environment.GetResourceString("Security_Generic").
5. Loop back to point 2.
6. (IsolatedStorage never gets to catch the FileNotFoundException, so it won't create a new one.)

The NotImplementedException or AgrumentException seems to force mscorlib to be loaded, and the loop is avoided. Maybe there's a another way of making it easier to find, though.

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) But this is strange... In normal code (not under MS test) it is working fine...

Comment: Yes, for me its also working fine if not running under MS Test. Also, it seems to work fine under MS Test on some of my coworker's computers, but not on mine. Just got a new computer, and even that didn't solve it. But, at least this works for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case exactly this happened **on some of the machines** when my code tried to create a **new** file in `IsolatedStorage`. After some research, it appeared to be really a bug and happens when the machine has non-English active locale set. Following code fixed the issue in my case:

```
var currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
var currentUiCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

var traceFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("system_log.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = currentUiCulture;
```

Comment: This worked on a BricsCAD plugin I had this problem with. Thanks for sharing.